# listing all street names

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i' m retrieving a city name using geocoder ***to get all street names of the a selected city***,so with

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocationName("Rome", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            for (int a = 0; a < addresses.size(); a++) {
                Address address = addresses.get(a);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    Log.e("street", " " + address.getAddressLine(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

i' m getting only **Rome,italy** and not all street names.

how i can change my code to achieve this?

is there another way to do thas using google api?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), the function ```getFromLocationName``` "Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the named location", that doesn't include all the streets

Comment: @chrki ok, is it possible to achieve what i want to do?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, at least not with Google Maps API. I found some results about OpenStreetMap, but that involves some data work that you need to do yourself, there seems to be no working online service for this task, as it's a very "expensive" task do perform. See [OSM Help](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/9816/the-best-way-to-extract-street-list), [OSM Help](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2980/how-do-i-list-all-the-streets-in-a-city-with-nominatim)